# Apollo GraphQL + DataLoader with array and multiple subsystems

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

If I have a schema looking like this:

```
A {
    Values: [B] 
}

B {
    ValueFromSubSystemX: Float
    ValueFromSubSystemY: Float
}
```

If the client do a query that looks like this:

```
A {
  Values {
    ValueFromSubSystemX
  }
}
```

I want to do a `ServiceX.GetAll()` and then do `ServiceX.load(id)` to load the cached data, but I don't want to do `ServiceY.GetAll()`, since I never do a `ServiceY.load(id)` (since the client never requested any information about SystemY).

Is there anyway to do this kind of dataloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One, not so pretty, solution that I've found is to request all in each request, and let the dataloader keep track of if we should go to subsystem for the call or not. A solution could look something like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  B: {
    async ValueFromSubSystemX (root, args, context) {
      await context.loaders.subSystemX.getAllValues('all')
      return await context.loaders.subSystemX.valueById(root.id)
    },
    async ValueFromSubSystemY (root, args, context) {
      await context.loaders.subSystemY.getAllValues('all')
      return await context.loaders.subSystemY.valueById(root.id)
    }
  }
}
```

`getAllValues` is now calling `valueById.prime(idFromSubSystem, valueFromSubSystem)`

Don't forget to turn off batching on `getAllValues`. If it isn't disabled, your dataloader could be really slow, depending on how you implemented it.